# Azure Push using MobileServiceClient

Tags: android, .net, azure, xamarin, push-notification

I am trying to get push notifications set up using the "Windows Azure Mobile Services" SDK (https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/).  however, I get the following error when I call the RegisterNativeAsync method, with no further information and very little help online:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered
>   while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

I assume it is some error XML coming back from azure, perhaps related some incorrect code below, but I have no idea of the content?

```
MobileServiceClient mobileServiceClient = new MobileServiceClient(myAppURI, myAppKey);
_push = mobileServiceClient.GetPush();
...
await _push.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceId);
```

It may well be that I am just using the wrong myAppURI / myAppKey, could anybody please provide a screenshot of where these may be as they seem to have different names all over the place?

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  Did you ever get it solved?  Thanks.